# Getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'server')" when trying to set up a socket connection

Tags: next.js, socket.io

I am following some code from GitHub and here is what I have so far.

```js
import {
  ClientToServerEvents,
  NextApiResponseWithSocket,
  ServerToClientEvents,
} from "@/types/socket-types";
import type { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export const GET = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseWithSocket) => {
  if (!res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("*First use, starting socket.io");

    const io = new Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents>(
      res.socket.server,
      { path: "/api/socket", addTrailingSlash: false }
    );

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.broadcast.emit("userServerConnection");
      socket.on("hello", (msg) => {
        socket.emit("hello", msg);
      });
      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("A user disconnected");
        socket.broadcast.emit("userServerDisconnection", socket.id);
      });
    });

    res.socket.server.io = io;
  } else {
    console.log("socket.io already running");
  }
  res.end();
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'server')`. The error is generated by the first `res.socket.server`.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that `res.socket` is null/undefined, so check that first.

Also, to avoid getting "...Cannot read properties of undefined" errors when accessing properties of objects, try something like this:

```
if (!res.socket?.server?.io)
```